# postgresql selecting the most representative value

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table in which objects have ids and they have names.  The ids are correct by definition, the names are almost always correct, but sometimes dirty incoming data causes names to be null or even wrong.

So I do a query like

```
SELECT id, name, AGGR1(a) as a, AGGR2(b) as b, AGGR3(c) as c
FROM my_table
WHERE d = 3
GROUP BY id
```

I'd like to have `name` in the results, but of course the above is wrong.  I'd have to group on `id, name`, in which case what should be one row sometimes becomes more than one -- say, id 2 has names 'John' (correct), 'Jon' (no, but only 1%), or NULL (also a small fraction).

Is there a construct or idiom in postgresql that lets me select what a human looking at the list would say is obviously the consensus name?

(I hear our postgres installation is finally being upgraded soon, if that matters here.)

**sample output, in case prose wasn't clear**

```
SELECT id, name, COUNT(id) as c
FROM my_table
WHERE d = 3
GROUP BY id

id    name       c

2     John    2000
2     Jon        3
2     (NULL)     5
```

vs

```
id    name       c

2     John    2008
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: You have to `GROUP BY` or use some aggregate also on `a`, `b` and `c`. What do you want, their `SUM()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the names with

```
WITH names as (
  SELECT 
    id, 
    name, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC) as rn
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY id, name
)
SELECT id, name
FROM names
WHERE rn=1;
```

and then do your calculations by `id` only, joining names from this query.